# How to validate value without wraping it in form?

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I need to [validate](https://element.eleme.io/2.4/#/en-US/component/form#validation) user input, but I do not want to wrap my data in Form, as shown in docs.

Is there any way to validate single value. Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/mvy0jesa/

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    myvalue: '', // I want to validate it without wrapping it in Form

    rules: {
        mycheck: [
          { required: true, message: 'Please input required', trigger: 'blur' },
          { min: 1, trigger: 'blur' }

        ],
    }

    }

})
```

template:

```
<el-form :model="myvalue" :inline="true" :rules="rules" ref="myvalue" >
    <el-form-item label="№" prop="mycheck">
        <el-input v-model="myvalue"></el-input>

    </el-form-item>

</el-form>
```

Comment: Please note this is a [element-ui](https://element.eleme.io/2.4/) related issue, the form validation element uses is [async-validator](https://github.com/yiminghe/async-validator)

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic example...

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

    data: {

        myvalue: '',
    focused : {
        mycheck: false
    },

     rules: {
        mycheck: [
          { required: true, message: 'Please input required', trigger: 'blur' },
          { min: 1, trigger: 'blur' }

        ],
    }
    }
})
```

Template:

```
  <el-card class="box-card">
    <el-input @blur="focused.mycheck = true" v-model="myvalue" :class="{error: !myvalue && focused.mycheck}"></el-input>
    <span v-show="!myvalue && focused.mycheck" class="error">{{rules.mycheck[0].message}}</span>
  </el-card>     
</div>
```

Here is the link to the working solution: https://jsfiddle.net/w6ovxa80/